# no-follow restriction removed by admin - user-generated or editorial?

Tags: seo, backlinks

On my forum website, I allow users to add their website link to their profile page. But as most forums do, I add no-follow to the link.

I am planning to implement a feature wherein I will remove the no-follow restriction based on a threshold number of helpful votes. Helpful votes are awarded by other members based on the usefulness of the interactions of a user.

Google generally ignores user-generated links like forum links (the right thing to do) for ranking purposes. But in my case, since I am removing the no-follow restriction, will the link be treated like an editorial one? Or will Google still treat the same as user-generated one? (as users created them in the first place.)